# ISO to IMG converting error

Tags: mac, iso, conversion, cd-image

I'm having trouble converting, with the following output `only a single input file can be specified`.  Anyone know where the issue is?

```
NAMEZs-air:~ NAMEZ$ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.img /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.iso
– hdiutil: convert: only a single input file can be specified
Usage: hdiutil convert -format -o [options] hdiutil convert -help –
```

*** ANSWERED
this is the correct code for converting from ISO to IMG
hdiutil convert -format UDRW /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.iso -o /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.img

Comment: The flag -o seems to mean "output" so can you try the same command with this flag between the route to the source and the destination? Somethint like hdiutil convert -format UDRW  /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.img -o /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.iso

Comment: hm, but the output is meant to be the .img?  I'm trying to use the Ubuntu  instructions here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: ok, I moved the -o and put the iso first, the img second and it worked!  thanks.

Comment: Yes, you were right, I tought the conversion was the other way around. Glad it worked anyway!

Answer (score 0):

muito bom so coloca o arquivo origem na frete hdiutil converter -format UDRW /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.iso -o /Users/NAMEZ/Downloads/ubuntu.img 
funciono no MAC OSX

Comment: Please write answers in English.